# Removed subnet, forwarding rogue software with Cisco firewall

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

As we moved to another firewall with fewer connectors (PIX 515 -> ASA 5510), I had to prune the network infrastructure a bit, so one of the subnets had to go. Now we've got one piece of hardware that still insists on reaching one of the servers via a hard-coded ip address. It might be a while until I get an update, so I need some tricks to work around that.

Now, as we were waiting for the new firewall, I had a temp Linux server set up, where I could forward any connections originating from one machine to the new address. Somehow I can't manage to do this over the ASDM.

So basically I need the following setup: Treat address *old-ip* (removed) as *new-ip* (new address), preferably only on machine *rogue-client*.

This is on a ASA 5510, IOS 8.2, ADM 6.3.

Comment: Is the rogue client and the server on different network segments?

Comment: Two different interfaces/subnets, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a policy NAT (sorry it's been about a year since i've done this so i'm a little rusty)

Something like the following should get you going:

```
(config)#access-list rougue_box permit host <old_ip>
(config)#static(<pre-nat_int>,<post-nat_int>) <new_ip> access-list rouge_box
```